# Event which triggers before DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

In my Firefox extension I am using `DOMContentLoaded` to detect page load and insert my HTML. Is there an event which triggers before this and still the document is available at that time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: This answer refers to XUL-based extensions. As of Firefox 57, this technology is obsolete. The functionality mentioned here is no longer available to extensions.

There is [`content-document-global-created` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) that is sent out when a document is created, before any content is added to it (to be precise, it happens when the browser receives the HTTP headers of the response and knows that it isn't a redirect or such). That's the earliest point where you can get the document. The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired once Gecko finishes downloading the contents of the document, that's the earlies point where you can access the complete DOM. In between there is a bunch of other events, e.g. lots of [progress listener events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) - which one you use depends on what you are trying to do, there is no general answer.

Comment: I am using this notification. It works. But this notification is generated for iframes also. How can I find whether the notification is from iframe or not?

Comment: @SelvarajMA: How about `event.target.top == event.target`?

Comment: I am using `subject.parent.length == 0`. That works. But body is not available when this notification is sent. Is there any solution for this. I tried using a clock which will check for availability for body once in every 10ms after this notification is received. But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @SelvarajMA: The page Wladimir linked to also mentions 'document-element-inserted', which is fired when the root element is inserted into the DOM. Why do you need the body specifically?

Comment: @Nickolay I need to do something like body.appendChild()

Comment: @SelvarajMA: How about `document.documentElement.appendChild()`?

Comment: all the links in this answer are now broken.

Comment: @rags2riches: That’s unsurprising given that they refer to obsolete functionality. As of Firefox 57, none of this functionality can be used by add-ons. Note the XUL tag, none of this is relevant any more…

Comment: @WladimirPalant I am not surprised. It was just a heads-up for users like me who came across this post whilst browsing. So the links and tags are no longer relevant while the question, taken on a more general level for any browser context, still is.

Comment: @rags2riches: I added a corresponding note to the answer. The problem is: there is a metric ton of answers referring to XUL-based extensions on this site, I alone have more than 200. Adding these notes manually isn’t practicable.